# Rewrite rule to pass all string after slash(/) to a php file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a php file that accepts a url as GET parameter `htttp://mywebsite.com/php/loadwebsite.php?q=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F`

I'm trying to write an htaccess that redirects all http to https and redirects links like `htttp://mywebsite.com/php/loadwebsite/http://example.com/` to `htttp://mywebsite.com/php/loadwebsite.php?q=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F`

I'm trying to make something similar to

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase   /
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^php/loadwebsite/(.+)$ loadwebsite.php?q=$1
```

The first part of htaccess code above redirects all http to https, but I can't figure out how to make the second part to redirect string after `php/loadwebsite.php/` to the php file `loadwebsite.php`.

So what I'm trying to accomplish is redirect the string after `php/loadwebsite.php/` to the php file `loadwebsite.php` and to `urlencode` that string to be able to use it in the php file after `urldecode` it again.

How can I do that?

Comment: Now what do you want to match? Your example URLs said `php/loadwebsite/`, but your RewriteRule is trying to match `php/loadwebsite.php/...`

Comment: Nevertheless, you should apply URL encoding for the “external” URLs already, otherwise this will easily fail for URLs that are a little more “complex” than the ones in your example.

Comment: @CBroe My bad, I edited my question.

Comment: @CBroe How can I decode the url after `php/loadwebsite/`

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? Not redirecting at all, redirecting to the wrong place, meteor strike …? I’d try and remove the two RewriteConds you have before that rule - _nothing_ under the path `/php/loadwebsite/...` exists physically anyway, right?

Comment: What problem are you facing with your current rule? Is it 404?